# When gradle build(war) in spring boot, can place the static files in the root?

Tags: spring, apache, spring-boot, gradle, static

I understand that in order to access static files in web server (apache), static files must be located outside of WEB-INF. however, the Spring boot starter project with gradle, builds static files into the WEB-INF. No search could find a setup that would build a static file outside of the WEB-INF. I don't know if there is something wrong with me. I need some advice.

Below is the basic spring boot starter project that was created for testing.

**enviorment**

spring boot 2.1.1, java 1.8

**layout**

```
src
  └ main
        └ java
            └ ...
        └ resources
            └ static
            └ templates
            └ application.properties
  └ test
```

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.1.1.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'war'

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    implementation('org.springframework.session:spring-session-core')
    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
    providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

**AS-IS war structure**

```
└META-INF
└org
└WEB-INF
    └classes
        └com
        └static
        └templates
        └application.properties
    └lib
    └lib-provided
```

**TO-BE war structure**

```
└META-INF
└org
└resources
    └static
    └templates
└WEB-INF
    └classes
        └com
        └application.properties
    └lib
    └lib-provided
```

thank you.

Comment: did you try the solution I proposed?

Answer (score 0):

See the `war` Gradle plugin documentation here [War Plugin - default settings](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/war_plugin.html#sec:war_default_settings):

> The default behavior of the War task is to copy the content of src/main/webapp to the root of the archive. Your webapp directory may of course contain a WEB-INF sub-directory, which may contain a web.xml file. Your compiled classes are compiled to WEB-INF/classes. All the dependencies of the runtime [1](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/war_plugin.html#sec:war_default_settings) configuration are copied to WEB-INF/lib.

If you move your resources folders `static` and `templates` into `src/main/webapp`, you should get the expected structure in the War archive.